# CMake "find_package" command on a package that was not installed is unexpectedly successful

Tags: c++, cmake

I am following [chapter-02/recipe-06](https://github.com/dev-cafe/cmake-cookbook/tree/master/chapter-02/recipe-06) in "[CMake Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/cmake-cookbook)". This particular example requires the [Eigen C++ libraries](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

I attempted to build the example and got the error that Eigen was not found.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

This was expected because the library was not installed on my system.

I then downloaded the ".zip" file for the Eigen libraries and unzipped it to an arbitrary location outside of my project. I created a "build" folder in the Eigen directory and ran `cmake ..` in the "build" folder. **(I only ran cmake - I did NOT build or install the package.)**

---

After running CMake on the Eigen build directory, I went back to the example code for "recipe-06" and it was magically able to find the Eigen library and built successfully even though Eigen was never built or installed.

Somehow just running CMake in the Eigen project made CMake aware of the Eigen libraries location. After doing this, any projects that do `find_package` to find Eigen3 somehow get the `${Eigen3_DIR}` variable defined and are able to find it.

---

Looking at the CMake documentation for `find_package` I don't see any explanation of why this works. Eigen is not in any of the typical locations that `find_package` searches. According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/find_package.html) it looks like it should NOT be found.

*Even more interesting - it doesn't matter where I put Eigen on my system. I can put it literally anywhere and it will still find it.*

According to everything I see in the documentation it should not be found... but it is found. So the question is how? Why does this work?

Additional info: I am using CMake version 3.13.3

Comment: Well, running CMake on Eigen create the cmake file, so you install it somewhere, you point your other CMake project to it and you are surprised that it works?

Comment: I didn't do any pointing of any kind. I just pasted the Eigen code in an arbitrary location and ran CMake on it. (I only ran the cmake step - I did not build or install it.) The Eigen code is an entirely separate from the other project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are doing. Are you running CMake on Eigen or on your own project?

Comment: I am running CMake in both, independently. They are in two entirely separate locations. The only reference to "Eigen" that my project has is the `find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED CONFIG)` line in its CMakeLists.txt file. I don't tell it where to look, so it is doing whatever "voodoo magic" `find_package` does by default.

Comment: And then your other project points to the proper Eigen location? Have you checked that you don't have a CMAKE_MODULE_PATH or similar pointing to a location where CMake would have put the .cmake file? Because otherwise, this is highly unlikely

Comment: I don't have any reference to the Eigen directory in my project except for the `${Eigen3_DIR}` variable it seems to magically generate on its own (I don't define this variable - `find_package` defines it after it somehow finds the package in some unknown magical way.) And yes it not only seems unlikely, it seems impossible - which is why I'm asking this question haha

Comment: Setting `Eigen3_DIR` is something that the user is setting, not CMake, at least that's how it usually works. Can you check again from a brand new build folder?

Comment: I tried completely wiping out the build folder and doing it again. I can even move Eigen somewhere else and it automatically sets `${Eigen3_DIR}` to the new location every time. According to the `find_package` documentation it sets the `<PackageName>_DIR` variable so I'm pretty sure `find_package` is somehow finding it and setting that variable. That variable is not listed explicitly in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the "recipe-06" project. The only reason I know it is being set is by running `cmake --system-information` from the "recipe-06/build" directory and searching the output.

Comment: Here is a link to the recipe-06 code so you can give it a try for yourself if you'd like: https://github.com/dev-cafe/cmake-cookbook/tree/master/chapter-02/recipe-06

Comment: For reference, when you run `find_package(Eigen3 ...)` it will in turn run [FindEigen3.cmake](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindEigen3.cmake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 "origins" of `XXXConfig.cmake` files, used internally by `find_package()` call.

Usually, `XXXConfig.cmake` file is produced when the project is **installed**, and the file contains information about installed libraries and headers.

But CMake provides also an [export()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/export.html) command, which allows to export **build tree**.

> `export(PACKAGE <name>)`
>
> Store the current build directory in the CMake user package registry for package `<name>`. The `find_package` command may consider the directory while searching for package `<name>`.

Eigen's `CMakeLists.txt` uses `export()` command, so the project becomes detectable with `find_package` just after running `cmake` for Eigen.

Comment: I didn't realize it, but `export` creates a Windows registry entry that CMake uses to find it. It makes sense now!